# Internet router on Raspberry Pi with easy graphical setup

Tags: networking, gui, raspberry-pi

I want to turn my Raspberry Pi 2 into an Internet router, i.e. it provides Internet access to many devices via Ethernet while itself is connected to the Internet via a guest WLAN account.

This is for my colleagues of the training department. They have trainings at the customer's site. The server is in the Internet and there are a number of hardware devices that need to connect to that server. The hosting company will typically just provide guest WLAN access.

Therefore, the setup of the WLAN will change often and might require opening a website first, then entering credentials in the browser before the real connections are possible.

My colleagues are not familiar with Raspbian / Linux, so I need a simple graphical user interface for them to set up the Router.

On the Ethernet side, things never change. It'll always be a local 192.168 network with static IP addresses for the devices and DHCP for the laptops of the training participants.

The Raspberry in question has the 7" 800 x 480 touch display connected via the internal DSI connector and a keyboard.

Is there any gratis or commercial application (I'd pay 50 € for it) that does this?

I have tried:

- OpenWrt, but it does not support the 7" touch display
- Raspbian - actually [I'm still configuring it (CodeReview.SE)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140056/bash-script-for-setting-up-a-lan-to-wlan-router), but it's cumbersome and very console related. I seldom do stuff like that and I think there must be an easier way

Note: this is not about creating a WLAN access point, it's the exact opposite way round.